# Unable to display contents of uploaded file on html page using flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I want to upload a csv file on the server and then want to display its contents in a separate route.

My init.py file:

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'C:/Users/parnal.patil/Documents/FLASKMiniProject/app/uploads'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route('/uploader', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def uploader():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        f = f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
        return render_template("uploader.html", data=f)
```

Here is the index.html file from where I add a link for file upload:

```
<form action = "/uploader" method = "POST"
     enctype = "multipart/form-data">
     <input type = "file" name = "file" />
     <br>
     <input type = "submit"/>
</form>
```

And the blank uploader.html file where I want to see the csv data.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<p>{{ data }}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

I considered adding the below code in my uploader view function but it doesn't work.

```
file = pd.read_csv(f, encoding= 'unicode_escape')
return render_template("uploader.html", data=file.to_html())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it using this code. The io.StringIO where we read the file and then decode it did the work.

```
@login_required
def uploader():
  f = request.files['file']
  if not f:
    return "No file"

  stream = io.StringIO(f.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
  file = pd.read_csv(stream)

  return render_template("uploader.html", data=file.to_html())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you hand over html code from your route and display it within your jinja2
template, certain characters which have a meaning in html are converted to
their entities by default. To avoid this behavior you can use the jinja2 filter
[`safe`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#safe).

Use the following in your template to display the table.
`{{ data | safe }}`

The [`save`](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/werkzeug.FileStorage.save.html)  function of the werkzeug.FileStorage class has no return value. If you save the file beforehand using the
`save`
function, the file has already been completely read.
To read the data again afterwards with pandas you have to set the pointer within the
file to the beginning with `seek`.

```
@app.route('/uploader', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def uploader():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        f.save(secure_filename(file.filename))
        f.seek(0)
        df = pd.read_csv(f, encoding='utf8')
        return render_template('uploader.html', data=df.to_html())
    # ...
```

Comment: I didn't try your code but I have posted the code that worked for me.